# How to fix project initialization with sequelize-cli that is giving errors?

Tags: mysql, sequelize.js, sequelize-cli

I have installed sequelize, sequelize-cli and mysql on my amazon cloud services using the following command

```
npm install --save sequelize@2.0.0-rc1 sequelize-cli mysql
```

After installation I tried the following command in the project root to initialize a project

```
node_modules/.bin/sequelize init
```

after running this command I got the following error and don't know whats wrong. How can I get the command to run successfully?

```
/var/www/html/node_modules/sequelize-cli/node_modules/fs-extra/lib/index.js:3
const assign = require('./util/assign')
^^^^^
SyntaxError: Use of const in strict mode.
    at Module._compile (module.js:439:25)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:474:10)
    at Module.load (module.js:356:32)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:312:12)
    at Module.require (module.js:364:17)
    at require (module.js:380:17)
    at Object.<anonymous> (/var/www/html/node_modules/sequelize-cli/lib/helpers/asset-helper.js:3:12)
    at Module._compile (module.js:456:26)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:474:10)
    at Module.load (module.js:356:32)
```